# SQL query to retrieve records that fall outside of a time range defined between two datetime fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to find anomolies in our work order system, and one of my where statements needs to retrieve records where work occurs out of a certian time frame in the last 30 days. I am trying to determine if any work occured before 6am or after 4pm.  My database has a datetime field storing this information.

So far i have this query:

```
Select WORKORDERID, DESCRIPTION, actualstartdate, actualfinishdate 
FROM [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER]
WHERE actualstartdate BETWEEN '2014-05-05 01:00:00.000'  AND '2014-06-05 23:00:00.000' 
  order by actualstartdate desc
```

How would i add a where statement to see if work in the actualstartdate column occured before 'yyyy-mm-dd 06:00:00.000' or after 'yyyy-mm-dd 16:00:00.000' in the actualfinishdate while still pulling from the last 30 days?

Comment: seems pretty straightforward, what was the error that you got when you tried your solution?

Comment: @Yuck You'd think that, but from the volume of incorrect answers, apparently not.

Comment: Edited for your appeasement All mighty..

Comment: To whoever mass downvoted all the answers, what exactly is wrong with them?

Comment: It wasn't me, but none of the downvoted answers actually solved the problem

Comment: @Anon They all should have solved the problem of getting rows that occurred outside of work hours between his provided hard coded dates.

Comment: @Vulcronos. No - they get values that are outside the range 06:00-16:59

Comment: Excerpts from the question it self - "How would I add a Where statement to see if work occurred in the actualstartdate column "***before***" yyyy-mm-dd 06:00:00.000 or "***after****" yyyy-mm-dd 16:00:00.000 while still pulling from the last 30 days?"

Comment: @godzilla2014  True but all the answers showed how to tie the daterange logic to hour logic.  If we need to tweak inclusions that's a relatively minor change, and a comment should have been left on at least one answer to say what was still wrong.

Comment: None of the downvoted solutions would flag an entry that started '2014-05-06 8:00:00.000' and finished '2014-05-07 10:00:00.000'.  It's not an issue of hours vs minutes; it's a fundamental logic flaw.

Comment: @Anon Of course, that finished before 4pm. Just on a different day.

Comment: @Vulcronos .. It was meant as a reply to another question.. and your comment is very right.. none of the answers deserved to be down voted. Except the one one who down voted all the answers :)

Comment: @Anon Why in the world should we flag an entry that started '2014-05-06 8:00:00.000' and finished '2014-05-07 10:00:00.000'?  The start date was after six and it finished before 10.  Nothing in the OP's post said work orders couldn't span days.

Comment: "I am trying to determine if any work occured before 6am or after 4pm."  If a work order runs overnight, the OP wants to find it.

Comment: I am pretty sure OP has got a gist of all the answers and is well on his way... so am I with a tarnished reputation :)

Comment: @Anon  I am still skeptical until the OP clarifies this requirement, but in a normal work order system some things span multiple days.  How can you tell the difference between a work order where everyone signs out at four as instructed and pick up the work the next day at six?  No work occurred outside the given times but the work order took multiple days to complete.

Answer (score 1):

Quick-and-dirty solution: select all rows and subtract the non-suspect rows

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f0651/1

```
Select WORKORDERID, DESCRIPTION, actualstartdate, actualfinishdate 
FROM [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER]
WHERE actualstartdate BETWEEN '2014-05-05 01:00:00.000'  AND '2014-06-05 23:00:00.000'
EXCEPT
Select WORKORDERID, DESCRIPTION, actualstartdate, actualfinishdate 
FROM [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER]
WHERE actualstartdate BETWEEN '2014-05-05 01:00:00.000'  AND '2014-06-05 23:00:00.000'
  AND actualstartdate  >= DATEADD(hour, 6,CAST(CAST(actualstartdate  AS date) AS datetime))
  AND actualfinishdate <= DATEADD(hour,16,CAST(CAST(actualfinishdate AS date) AS datetime))
  AND CAST(actualstartdate AS date) = CAST(actualfinishdate AS date)
```

Comment: What's the point of the last line?  Why would the start date need to be the same as the finish date?

Comment: Because you want to catch an entry that runs overnight, even if it starts and finishes within the valid hours.

Comment: @godzilla an entry that completes at 16:00:00.000 on the dot will get selected by the second subquery, which means it does *not* appear in the output.  See SQLFiddle

Comment: @Anon Having two queries seems over complicated and bound to run slower than a single query.  You should be able to easily write your solution in a single subquery by changing negating your three additional filters.

Comment: @Vulcronos this is a quick-and-dirty, easy-to-read, easy-to-tweak solution designed for what sounded like a one-off job.  If you wish to write a high-performance alternative, go ahead, and I'll gladly vote for it.

Comment: @Anon  I did write an alternative.  Its basically your second subquery negated without the last check.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18f07/13)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE WORKORDER
    ([WORKORDERID] int, [DESCRIPTION] varchar(3), [actualstartdate] datetime, [actualfinishdate] datetime)
;

INSERT INTO WORKORDER
    ([WORKORDERID], [DESCRIPTION], [actualstartdate], [actualfinishdate])
VALUES
    (1, 'w1', '2014-05-07 01:00:00', '2014-05-07 05:00:00'),
    (2, 'w2', '2014-05-07 04:00:00', '2014-05-07 12:00:00'),
    (3, 'w3', '2014-05-07 05:59:00', '2014-05-07 12:00:00'),
    (4, 'w4', '2014-05-07 06:00:00', '2014-05-07 12:00:00'),
    (5, 'w5', '2014-05-07 06:01:00', '2014-05-07 16:00:00'),
    (6, 'w6', '2014-05-07 06:01:00', '2014-05-07 16:01:00'),
    (7, 'w7', '2014-05-07 06:01:00', '2014-05-08 12:01:00')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
Select WORKORDERID, DESCRIPTION, actualstartdate, actualfinishdate
FROM [WORKORDER]
WHERE actualstartdate BETWEEN '2014-05-05 01:00:00.000'  AND '2014-06-05 23:00:00.000' 
and (CAST(actualstartdate AS date) = CAST(actualfinishdate AS date)
     and (((DATEPART(hh, actualstartdate)*3600)+
     (DATEPART(mi, actualstartdate)*60)+
     DATEPART(ss, actualstartdate)) < 21600 or
      ((DATEPART(hh, actualfinishdate)*3600)+
     (DATEPART(mi, actualfinishdate)*60)+
     DATEPART(ss, actualfinishdate)) > 57600) or
     CAST(actualstartdate AS date) <> CAST(actualfinishdate AS date))
  order by actualstartdate desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18f07/13/0)**:

```
| WORKORDERID | DESCRIPTION |            ACTUALSTARTDATE |           ACTUALFINISHDATE |
|-------------|-------------|----------------------------|----------------------------|
|           6 |          w6 | May, 07 2014 06:01:00+0000 | May, 07 2014 16:01:00+0000 |
|           7 |          w7 | May, 07 2014 06:01:00+0000 | May, 08 2014 12:01:00+0000 |
|           3 |          w3 | May, 07 2014 05:59:00+0000 | May, 07 2014 12:00:00+0000 |
|           2 |          w2 | May, 07 2014 04:00:00+0000 | May, 07 2014 12:00:00+0000 |
|           1 |          w1 | May, 07 2014 01:00:00+0000 | May, 07 2014 05:00:00+0000 |
```

Comment: What in the world is the point of all the addition on the hours/minutes/seconds?  Seems way over complicated for the needed solution.  Also, the op included both actualstartdate and actaulfinishdate in their requirements.

Comment: The point is that we need to exclude entries that finish at 16:00:00...but include those at 16:00:01

Comment: I can understand that.  It should be much easier to read doing it Anon's way: getting rid of the time portion of the date and adding a given number of hours to it and seeing how the original compares.

Comment: You are right...but since Anon already use this method...I just pointed out another way of doing it. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the datepart function to look at the hour:

```
SELECT  WORKORDERID ,
        DESCRIPTION ,
        actualstartdate ,
        actualfinishdate
FROM    [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER]
WHERE   actualstartdate BETWEEN '2014-05-05 01:00:00.000'
                        AND     '2014-06-05 23:00:00.000'
        AND (DATEPART(HOUR, actualstartdate) <= 6
        OR DATEPART(HOUR, actualstartdate) => 16)
ORDER BY actualstartdate DESC
```

Answer (score -1):

You can easily get the hour portion of the date as follows:

```
DATEPART(hh, actualstartdate);
```

Use it as follows:

```
Select WORKORDERID, DESCRIPTION, actualstartdate, actualfinishdate 
FROM [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER]
WHERE actualstartdate BETWEEN '2014-05-05 01:00:00.000'  AND '2014-06-05 23:00:00.000' 
AND (DATEPART(hh, actualstartdate) < 6 or (DATEPART(hh, actualfinishdate) >= 16)
  order by actualstartdate desc
```

This will get all rows between your given dates that occurred before six in the morning or after four at night.

**Edit:**
If you want to allow an actualfinishdate of exactly 16 hundred you can change the second clause to:

```
or actualfinishdate > DATEADD(hh, 16, cast(actualfinishdate as date))
```

This would check if the actual finish date is after 4.

Comment: This will include entries that finish at 16:00:00...OP want to exclude them

Comment: @FabienTheSolution  Added a way to include exactly 4 pm.

Answer (score -3):

```
Select WORKORDERID, DESCRIPTION, actualstartdate, actualfinishdate 
FROM [CityWorks].[AZTECA].[WORKORDER]
WHERE actualstartdate BETWEEN '2014-05-05 01:00:00.000'  AND '2014-06-05 23:00:00.000' 
and 
   (CONVERT(time,actualstartdate )<'06:00' or CONVERT(time,actualfinishdate )> '16:00')
  order by actualstartdate desc
```